# How can I get the normalized matrix out of this function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am given a dataset called stocks_df. Each column has stock prices for different stocks in each day. I am trying  to normalize it and return it as a matrix. So, each column will have normalized for a stock for each day.
Wrote up this function-

```
def normalized_prices(stocks_df):
  normalized=np.zeros((stocks_df.shape[0],len(stocks_df.columns[1:])))
  for i in range(1,len(stocks_df.columns[1:])+1):
    for j in range(0,stocks_df.shape[0]+1):
      normalized[i,j]=((stocks_df[i][j]/stocks_df[0][i]))
  return normalized
```

And then tried to call the function-

```
normalized_prices(stocks_df)
```

But I'm getting this error-
[image]

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks you want to divide everything by the first column, so you can simply do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(123)

stocks_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(20,10)))

stocks_df.div(stocks_df[0],axis=0)

      0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7          8         9
0   1.0  0.410843  0.325716  0.791585  1.033023  0.607502  1.408195  0.983288   0.690529  0.563008
1   1.0  2.124407  1.277973  0.173898  1.159877  2.150474  0.531770  0.511256   1.548909  1.549713
2   1.0  1.338951  1.141952  0.963150  1.138780  0.509077  0.570284  0.359809   0.462979  0.994601
3   1.0  4.708772  4.677955  5.360028  4.623317  3.390277  4.628973  9.699688  10.250916  5.448532
4   1.0  0.185300  0.508509  0.664836  1.388421  0.401401  0.774152  1.579542   0.832571  0.982277
```

This gives you every column divided by the first. Now you just need to subset this output:

```
stocks_df.div(stocks_df[0],axis=0).iloc[:,1:]
```